# MVC 5: Cant send certain values in URL parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url, exchangewebservices

I am trying to send chars like `: / .` in asp.net mvc 5 to an API controller endpoint, but it fails as soon as I try something containing certain chars. For example, I can't send `message:hi`, I have to change it to `message_hi` to get it working.

I am trying to send an email using Exchange and the body (containing an URL and other info) won't go through.

My API Controller:

```
[Route("send/{adress}/{subject}/{body}")]
        public void SendEmail(string adress, string subject, string body)
        {
            Office365MailSender ms = new Office365MailSender();
            EmailDto email = new EmailDto(adress, subject, body);
            ms.Send(email);
        }
```

Calling the above endpoint from my application:

```
public static async Task<string> SendMail(IPhoneCall phoneCall)
        {
            var email = new EmailEntity(phoneCall);

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var uri = new Uri("http://url/email/send/" + email.Recipient + "/" + email.Title + "/" + email.body);
                var msg = await client.GetAsync(uri);
            }
            return "Email Sent";
        }
```

An example of a value of the `uri` variable would be:
`http://url/email/send/myemail@outlook.com/Hello There/Hi,\nThis is a url you can use for stuff: https://thisisit.com. \n Thanks bye.`

I've tried `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` on the body before I send it, but that does nothing. Does anyone know how to send strings containing these type of chars?

Comment: It's better to use POST and send the message in the body of the request. Don't try to encode such special characters in the path portion of an url. You will fail: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Hi, thanks! Could you provide a short code snippet on how to do that and post it as an answer? :) Thanks for the link, will read through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you using the POST verb in order to send the body of the message. So you could start by writing a view model:

```
public class MailMessageViewModel
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

that your Web API action will take as parameter:

```
[Route("send")]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult SendEmail(MyViewModel model)
{
    Office365MailSender ms = new Office365MailSender();
    EmailDto email = new EmailDto(model.Address, model.Subject, model.Body);
    ms.Send(email);
    return this.Ok();
}
```

and then you could invoke like this:

```
var email = new EmailEntity(phoneCall);

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var uri = new Uri("http://url/email/send");
    var content = new StringContent(
        JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
        {
            Address = email.Recipient,
            Subject = email.Title,
            Body = email.body,
        }),
        UnicodeEncoding.UTF8,
        "application/json");

    var msg = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
}
```

Comment: Just what I needed, really struggled to understand how to properly use get/post and how to format uri/content. Thanks a ton!

Comment: is there a replacement for `IHttpActionResult` if I am using a normal controller? Trying to get this to work and just end up getting 404's atm.

Comment: Which version of Web API are you using? What do you mean by *normal controller*? In Web API controllers inherit `ApiController` and controller actions are methods on this controller that must return `IHttpActionResult`.

Comment: That was my mistake, sorry. All I need is `[Route("send")]` even though I'm sending a parameter? I dont need to use  `[Route("send/{model}")]` ?

Comment: Nope, all you need is already shown in my answer: `[Route("send")]`. Because your controller action takes a complex object as parameter, the framework assumes that this parameter can only come from the body of the request. The `Route` attribute is only used to indicate the path portion of the url that needs to match.